# Text to Predict Numbers

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I've got a dataset (~5.5k) of posts with their text and how many "likes" each post got. I'm looking for an algorithm that'll use the text to predict the number of likes a post will get.

I'm thinking of using the Apriori algorithm, but I've only seen it used in cases where we've got something like a shopping list; [A, B] -> C and so on.

We don't need to predict an exact number, it is fine if the posts are arranged into classes based on their number of likes, and each post's class is predicted.

What algorithm should I use? I'm using Rapidminer.

Comment: please note that number of likes depends largely on circumstance, meaning that two posts with exact same words posted on different times where different topics are on the hype will most likely receive different number of likes due to different circumstances

Comment: Yes, this is true. I've got more data that could be taken into consideration such as each poster's number of followers. I want to see if any prediction can be made only based on the words and then improved upon by adding other attributes later. @NikosM.